# Shortest program to throw NullPointerException in Java

Tags: code-golf, java

I find `NullPointerException` to be interesting since there are no explicit pointers in Java. Here is a program that throws such an exception.

```
class c {
  public static void main(String[]s) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
}
```

What is the shortest Java program that throws `NullPointerException`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694872/

Comment: We strongly discourage single-language challenges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 62 Bytes (17 byte statement)

-2 bytes thanks to @PeterTaylor.

```
class C{public static void main(String[]s){s=null;s.clone();}}
```

Without knowing about the `throw` trick, this is the first thing that occurred to me. Using the main class's type is the shortest one available, and casting `null` is shorter than declaring `C c=null;`. `notify` is also the shortest method on an object that doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: 19 bytes, see [this Meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7516/53748)

Comment: @JonathanAllan doesn't the question ask for a "java program"? According to that meta post, the full program is required unless only a function is requested.

Comment: it was not specified as "full program" [Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/53748) (every Java program will have that same boilerplate anyway - so to compare them we can just count the content).

Comment: `((C)null).wait();` will work too.

Comment: `wait`'s declaration throws InterruptedException, so the class will not compiler without a try/catch or throws declaration.

Comment: Compiles, runs and raises a NullPointerException at [ideone](http://ideone.com/ONWC6E).

Comment: You don't need a class name at all since you have a variable. `s=null;s` is one char shorter than `((C)null)`

Comment: @JonathanAllan that only works with the added `throws` declaration on `main`.

Comment: @mackthehobbit Ah, yes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor huh, that didn't occur to me at all. Nice!

Comment: `clone()` also requires a `throws` because of `CloneNotSupportedException`

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8 - <s>56</s> 53 bytes (11 byte snippet)

```java
interface P{static void main(String[]a){throw null;}}
```

**[ideone](http://ideone.com/EdRkRn)**

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html):

> #### Class NullPointerException
>
> ...
> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:
> ...
>
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

Comment: That is completely missing the point of the meta question and answer you linked to, which is about full program vs function. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2423/194

Comment: Yes. You can save a byte by using `enum` instead of `class`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor could not get that to compile, but found a [useful tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64713/53748) about `Interface` having default `public` scopes in Java 8.

Comment: It seems to need the declaration statement to be closed with a semicolon [ideone](http://ideone.com/BovJeF) which is still 56, what did I miss?